# Не могу ничего скомпилировать с MSYS2 на Rust

Tags: rust, msys2

Мой тулчейн - -x86_64-pc-windows-gnu

При компиляции некоторых крейтов возникает такая ошибка:

> error: linking with `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe` failed: exit code: 1
>     |
>     = note: "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe" "-fno-use-linker-plugin" "-Wl,--nxcompat" "-nostdlib" "-m64" "C:\msys64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\crt2.o" "C:\Users\Серега\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rsbegin.o" "-L" "C:\msys64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" "-L" "C:\Users\Серега\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib" "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.10.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.11.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.12.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.13.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.14.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.15.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.6.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.7.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.8.rcgu.o" "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.9.rcgu.o" "-o" "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.exe" "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.58vez94npxuacrts.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\deps" "-L" "C:\Users\Серега\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib" "-Wl,--start-group" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "C:\Users\Серега\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libstd-492039e7b59897c1.rlib" "C:\Users\Серега\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libpanic_unwind-d14439ab2380c306.rlib" "C:\Users\Серега\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libhashbrown-40863006d2e82898.rlib" "C:\Users\Серега\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-c1a3c8607a0d2bc8.rlib" "C:\Users\Серега\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libbacktrace-10f638dfe59512a7.rlib" "C:\Users\Серега\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libbacktrace_sys-67f702d35b36cfda.rlib" "C:\Users\Серега\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\librustc_demangle-083263c705effe33.rlib" "C:\Users\Серега\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libunwind-fd8f81e7d13c1af1.rlib" "C:\Users\Серега\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libcfg_if-a9bb878861bd54a0.rlib" "C:\Users\Серега\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\liblibc-44f95d9dce6e9c0d.rlib" "C:\Users\Серега\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\liballoc-786bffd49d9c3f5f.rlib" "C:\Users\Серега\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\librustc_std_workspace_core-bd70d4b1acc8d7af.rlib" "C:\Users\Серега\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libcore-d1631a47e8743fde.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "C:\Users\Серега\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libcompiler_builtins-cf2c747a9d7d25a8.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-ladvapi32" "-lws2_32" "-luserenv" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "-lgcc_eh" "-lpthread" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lmingwex" "-lmingw32" "-lgcc" "-lmsvcrt" "-lmsvcrt" "-luser32" "-lkernel32" "C:\Users\Серега\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rsend.o"
>     = note: gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rsbegin.o: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.0.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.1.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.10.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.11.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.12.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.13.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.14.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.15.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.2.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.3.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.4.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.5.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.6.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.7.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.8.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.build_script_build.a56o6j5o-cgu.9.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега\Desktop\RUST\vk_bot\vk_api\target\debug\build\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-5fffc0297b4e583e\build_script_build-5fffc0297b4e583e.58vez94npxuacrts.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libstd-492039e7b59897c1.rlib: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libpanic_unwind-d14439ab2380c306.rlib: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libhashbrown-40863006d2e82898.rlib: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-c1a3c8607a0d2bc8.rlib: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libbacktrace-10f638dfe59512a7.rlib: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libbacktrace_sys-67f702d35b36cfda.rlib: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\librustc_demangle-083263c705effe33.rlib: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libunwind-fd8f81e7d13c1af1.rlib: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libcfg_if-a9bb878861bd54a0.rlib: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\liblibc-44f95d9dce6e9c0d.rlib: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\liballoc-786bffd49d9c3f5f.rlib: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\librustc_std_workspace_core-bd70d4b1acc8d7af.rlib: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libcore-d1631a47e8743fde.rlib: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libcompiler_builtins-cf2c747a9d7d25a8.rlib: No such file or directory
>             gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Серега.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rsend.o: No such file or directory

В чем ошибка? Что я забыл установить?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема был в том, что путь содержал не ASCII символы